# Trying to find HREF from table with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, xpath

Webscraping a table into an Excel-file. Its a "Dynamic" table per 10 rows.

All the data is placed into Excel correctly, But having issues with the HREF-data.

The issue i am facing is that some rows dont have a HREF. I am using the following Xpath:

```
map = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="table_1"]/tbody//td[12]/a')
```

To get the HREF:

```
.get_attribute("href")[30:].split(",%20")[0]
.get_attribute("href")[30:].split(",%20")[1]
```

Via above Xpath is can find every HREF, but in case of NO HREF in the row, the following HREF-data is placed into the row where NO HREF-data should be.

Tried the below (without the "/a") but it returns nothing.

```
map_test = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table_1"]/tbody//td[12]')
```

When below code is used, it returns the text content which is not what I need, but keeps the data where is should be.

```
.get_attribute("textContent")
```

Any idea how i can find the HREFs and keep the data in the rows where it should be?

Comment: Check the result,  For example: len(href). if len(href) == 0 then assign some value. Use an if loop.

Comment: I"m guessing the page hasn't loaded the element. Try using WebDriverWait

Comment: Do you mean that some anchor tags have no `@href`?

Comment: define `attr = element.get_attribute("href")[30:].split(",%20")[0]` then into the row you place `attr if attr else ''`

Comment: Tried the if loop. It assign the value at the empty row but continues to concatenate the following rows incorrectly. WebDriverWait i didnt try. I already use time.sleep(2.5). @soundwave, can you please explain further. i am working with a dictionary: if key == 'latitude': data[key] = objects[key][i].get_attribute("href")[30:].split(",%20")[0]. Let me know if more code is required.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the full code otherwise is hard to help